# Is there a way to alphabetize attendees in Outlook meeting invites (using Exchange Server)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have an Outlook meeting invite multiple people on it, but in the ‘To:’ field of the appointment tab and on the ‘Scheduling Assistant’ tab people show up in the order they were added, not alphabetically.

This makes it difficult to scan the list to see if a given person is already on it.

Is there a way to alphabetize the list of people who have been invited to a given meeting?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option available in Outlook to sort attendees list alphabetically. You may check the method mentioned in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0e2f0503-0bd9-4bd5-86ab-e9e871101f7c/sort-email-recipient?forum=outlook) as a workaround. Or you may try the steps below:

1. Switch to Appointment View, locate in the To field, press Ctrl+A to select all the recipients, press Ctrl+C to copy the list.
2. Open Excel, paste the recipients list in the worksheet.
   [image]
3. All the recipient will be put into a single cell, but don't worry, we can split them via Data > Text to Columns:
   [image: List item]
4. Select the recipients list in Row 1, press Ctrl + C to copy them.
5. Right-Click in Cell A2 or any other blank cell, choose Transpose in Paste Options:
   [image]
6. Delete Row1, select Column A, delete all extra spaces using Ctrl+H(Replace all spaces)go to Home > Sort&Filter > Sort A to Z.